# i want add 3 line with sed or awk command in file config.xml

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed

I have a linux centos 7 server and i want Below lines to file with name config.xml using sed command

```html
<vhostMap>
  <vhost>google</vhost>
  <domain>google.com, www.google.com</domain>
</vhostMap>
```

i want add this lines after line 10 at config.xml file

i want add this with a command at centos7, its possible?
i have searched and i saw this is possible with sed or awk command

how i can do this with sed or awk command?

Comment: Add config.xml to your question.

Comment: I believe you asked the same question a few hours ago.

Comment: @Cyrus what your mean?

Comment: @Błotosmętek correct, but now i looking done this with a command line, not a code and save in python file, understand? i want done this with a command line, once i run command, it done.

Comment: Then please remove "python" and "perl" from the list of tags…

Comment: @Błotosmętek so what i should add? sed is not a method at perl or python?

Comment: `sed` is a separate program in Linux, has nothing to do with either Perl or Python. So is `awk`.

Comment: @Błotosmętek ok i added unix, its correct?

Comment: wrt [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60581653/i-want-add-3-line-with-sed-or-awk-command-in-a-file#comment107178245_60581653) - What part of `Add config.xml to your question` is unclear?

Comment: @EdMorton what your mean i add config.xml to my question?

Comment: On your computer you have a file named "config.xml". You have a question posted here asking for help to modify that file. So, [edit] your question to include the contents of "config.xml" so we can see the file that you want to add text to so we can help you to do that.

Answer (score 4):

GNU sed:

```
sed '10a <vhostMap>\n  <vhost>google</vhost>\n  <domain>google.com,www.google.com</domain>\n</vhostMap>' config.xml
```

Comment: it just show me as a output, but when i open file config.xml then this lines there is not on that file, what i should do if i want put this lines at config.xml file

Comment: Use `sed -i` with `-i` or `--in-place` option.

Answer (score 0):

Almost the same with `awk`:

```
awk '{ print $0 ; if(NR == 10) printf "<vhostMap>\n  <vhost>google</vhost>\n  <domain>google.com, www.google.com</domain>\n</vhostMap>\n" }' config.xml
```

Comment: it just show me as a output, but when i open file config.xml then this lines there is not on that file, what i should do if i want put this lines at config.xml file

Comment: Yes, of course - standard `awk` doesn't have `--inplace` option. You need to save the output in some temoprary file and then to move its content to config.xml.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed and shell):

```
cat <<\! | sed '10r /dev/stdin' file
<vhostMap>
  <vhost>google</vhost>
  <domain>google.com, www.google.com</domain>
</vhostMap>
!
```

Place the lines to be appended in a here-doc and append them after line 10 of the file by reading them in as stdin via a pipe.